# How can I speed up an sql query that round trips between two tables

Tags: mysql, performance, php, query-performance

I first posted this question on stackoverflow, and now I see this site, seems more relevant.

These tables are not that big, but the time taken to process this query is long.

What can I do with the following queries to speed up the process taken to return results?

```
$chat_alg = mysqli_query($con, "
    SELECT sid, COUNT(*) as frequency
    FROM plays
    WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY && sid != '' 
    GROUP BY sid
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row_chat_alg = mysqli_fetch_array($chat_alg)) {
    $chart_songs[] = $row_chat_alg['sid'];
}

$imploded_songs = implode($chart_songs, ',');

$projects = $dbh->query("
       SELECT * FROM music
       WHERE perms != 'c' && sid IN($imploded_songs) 
       ORDER BY FIELD(sid,$imploded_songs) 
       limit 50
");

...
```

This tables are growing, I'm worried that maintaining them will be a problem if this is already slow.

Comment: There are two queries here. Which is the slow one?

Comment: I don't because the first one depends on the second one.

Comment: You do. There are quite clearly two queries, executed separately. You also seem to be executing them differently. One with mysqli_query, the other using $dbh->query. So I'll ask again, which is the slow one?

Comment: Which query is slow? What are the execution plans for the two queries?

Answer (score 2):

From my (rather limited) knowledge of php, I assume you want to combine the two queries into one:

```
SELECT m.*, p.frequency 
FROM 
  ( SELECT sid, COUNT(*) as frequency
    FROM plays
    WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY 
      AND sid <> '' 
    GROUP BY sid
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 50 
  ) AS p
  JOIN music AS m
    ON m.sid = p.sid
WHERE m.perms <> 'c' 
ORDER BY m.frequency DESC ;
```

As for efficiency, it's better to tune the first query separately and then this combined one.

An index on `plays (sid, time)` should help for the first query. For the second, if there is an index on `music (sid)`, it should be quite efficient as it's a join to only 50 rows of `music`.